# WordPress: Blog template not appearing when going on to the URL

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have registered a custom post type called `blog`:

```
register_post_type(
    'blog',
    build_post_args(
        'blog', 'Blogs', 'Blog',
        array(
            'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-welcome-write-blog',
            'menu_position' => 20,
            'has_archive'   => true,
            'public'        => true,
        )
    )
);
```

This loads fine in the WordPress backend and I have created a test post within `blog`.

I have then created **archive-blog.php**, which has the following:

```
<?php get_header(); ?> 

<div class="blogPost">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-12">
                this is a test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But, when I go to `/blog`, it doesn't show the "this is a test" test.

Similarly, I have **single-post.php**, which has the following:

```
<?php get_header(); ?> 

<div>
    test
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>          
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

and when I go to `/blog/test`, the content in my test post within `blog` isn't appearing, neither is the test text.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try changing the post name from `blog` to something else like `article`. because it may conflict with the WordPress default `blog` page.

Comment: @sssurii - I've changed `blog` to `articles` and still seeing the same results.

Comment: Did you go to Settings > Permalinks to clear the permalink cache? Also, it should be `single-blog.php`.